# The request url "F:\Anish\#\react\churi\Expense-Tracker\src\main.jsx" is outside of Vite serving allow list

Tags: reactjs, vite

I cloned my friend's vite project in my system. Installed the required packages even with using --force and audit fix. The Project runs with no error but when the url is opened on website I couldn't see any contents in it except a blank (white) website and in console I am getting the following Error.

> The request url "F:\Anish#\react\churi\Expense-Tracker\src\main.jsx" is outside of Vite serving allow list. - F:/Anish/#/react/churi

> Refer to docs https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-fs-allow for configurations and more details.

*This is my vite config file*

**vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    fs: {
      // Allow serving files from one level up to the project root
      allow: ['..']
    }
  }
```

This is Project's Directory Tree

```
F:.
|   .gitignore
|   index.html
|   package-lock.json
|   package.json
|   vite.config.js
|   
+---public
|       vite.svg
|       
\---src
    |   App.css
    |   App.jsx
    |   index.css
    |   main.jsx
    |   
    +---assets
    |       react.svg
    |       
    \---components
        \---Signin
                Signin.css
                Signin.jsx
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <title>Vite + React</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try removing the entirety of the `server:` portion of your config. The `allow: ['..']` is only to serve files that are outside of your project root (which none of your files are).

Comment: @clxrity Thankyou for the answer but even after removing the entire server part in config file I am still getting that is outside of  Vite serving allow list error. 
`export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  
  )}`

Answer (score 0):

It's the "#" in your file path. It breaks the web server. Change your path or move your app to root and run it from there. I bet error goes away.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with supporting information, explaining how this solves the issue as well supporting links to documentation/tutorials.